# deleting user comment gives value null flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to enable user to delete comments. However, this code

```
deleteComment(BuildContext context) async {
  DocumentSnapshot doc = await 
    commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments')
    .doc('commentId').get();
  CommentModel comment = CommentModel.fromJson(doc.data());
  commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments')
    .doc(comment.commentId).delete();
 }
```

gives me error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (23933): Receiver: null
E/flutter (23933): Tried calling: []("username")
E/flutter (23933): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core- 
patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (23933): #1      new CommentModel.fromJson 
(package:blahblah/comments.dart:17:20)
E/flutter (23933): #2      _CommentsState.deleteComment 
(package:blahblah/comment.dart:465:41)
E/flutter (23933): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23933):
```

In my comment model class I do have a username, same as in my firestore collection. Why would this be null? thanks

[image: firestore colection]

UPDATE:

i have updated the method to this:

```
deleteComment(BuildContext context) async {
DocumentReference documentReference = 
commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments').doc();
await commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments')
.doc(documentReference.id).delete();
}
```

and it does nothing! I think, I am not referencing the doc Id correctly, as I tried setting the doc Id as the userId and then deleting the doc(userId), and it worked.
my adding comment method is:

```
addComments() async {
bool isBlocked = true == await 
blockedRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('blocked')
.where('blockingUserId', isEqualTo: 
widget.post.userId).where('blockedUserId', isEqualTo: currentUserId());
String commentsTEC = filter.censor(commentTEC.text);
DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(currentUserId()).get();
user = UserModel.fromJson(doc.data());

if (!isBlocked)
commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection("comments")
.doc().set({
  "username": user.username,
  "comment": commentsTEC,
  "timestamp": timestamp,
  "userDp": user.photoUrl,
  "userId": user.id,
});
else {
  showInSnackBar(Languages.of(context).userIsBlocked);
}
```

Help me please, to correctly reference the doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no document named `commentId` in your screenshot. Did you mean to use the `commentId` variable, rather than the static string?

```
DocumentSnapshot doc = await 
  commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments')
  .doc(commentId).get();
  //    remove "" here
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me the same error...

Comment: That could be, but this was definitely a problem. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a horribly inefficient interactive debugger, so instead of saying "the same error" I recommend stepping through the code in a local debugger, and checking the variables at each line in turn. Does your `commentId` variable have the right value?